# Alert is using a language other English to display the alert's title (SharePoint 2010)

Tags: sharepoint

I have a SharePoint 2010 portal, and it seems as though some people receive alert's with a language other than English for the alert's title.

You have successfully created an alert for '럢镛乪佟犋֣␓'

Can someone help me understand how that would happen? Is that a configuration on the SharePoint side? Configuration on each site? Configuration in Outlook?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Alert is using a language other English to display the alert's title (SharePoint 2010)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4028168/alert-is-using-a-language-other-english-to-display-the-alerts-title-sharepoint)

Comment: Hm, that's mine... Must have accidently posted twice. Weird. Just deleted the other post.